# Is finally block in C# a must?

Tags: c#, finally

What is the difference between 2 conditions? Every time when method1 or method2 runs, there should be a code block that is required to run. It seems to me that 2 method are the same.

```
// example method1
void Method1(void)
{
    try
    {
        // do something
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // do something
    }
    finally
    {
        // do something whenever method1 runs
    }
}

// example method2
void Method2(void)
{
    try
    {
        // do something
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // do something
    }

    // do something whenever method2 runs
}
```

Finally block seems to be unnecessary for me.

Comment: You need to be concrete about the `do something`s to make this a question.

Comment: depends on what 'do something' does

Comment: Please read the following for more info. Finally is optional where you could release resources after all processing is done. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Your exception in Method2 would mean you might not ever get to the end of the method. In Method 1 finally will always run. Not posted as an answer because I will leave someone else to give examples etc.

Comment: No, they are not the same. A `finally` block ensures that the code it contains runs, regardless of what else happens.

Comment: don't catch what you can't handle

Comment: VB.NET question but pretty much the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158667/why-use-finally-in-try-catch

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your first example, you could re-throw the exception and the code inside the finally would still run. This would not be possible in the second example.

If you choose not to re-throw the exception, then yes there is little difference. However, this is considered ***bad form*** - very *rarely* should you need to consume an exception that you cannot ***explicitly handle***.

It is a keyword to help you with code execution flow. When you throw an exception the execution flow of the code is affected (like using `return`), the `finally` keyword allows you to express that when an exception occurs (or you `return` from a `try`) you still want execution to do something as it's leaving.

To answer the question facetiously, it is a must when you need it and not when you don't.

---

**Further Reading**

To be on the safe side, before you attempt to start making use of this keyword, please read the documentation for it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx

And the exception handling keywords in general:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7fekhdy.aspx

---

**Examples**

Catch an exception to do something with it, then re-throw it. Use `finally` to call any tidy-up code:

```
try
{
    OpenConnectionToDatabase();
    // something likely to fail
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log(ex);
    throw;  
    // throw ex; // also works but behaves differently
}
// Not specifying an exception parameter also works, but you don't get exception details.
//catch (Exception)
//{
//    Log("Something went wrong);
//    throw;
//}
finally
{
    CloseConnectionToDatabase();
}
```

Don't register any interest in catching exceptions, but use `finally` to tidy-up code:

```
try
{
    OpenConnectionToDatabase();
    // something likely to fail
}
finally
{
    CloseConnectionToDatabase();
}
```

Return from your `try` because it looks nicely formatted, but still use `finally` to tidy-up code:

```
try
{
    OpenConnectionToDatabase();
    return 42;
}
finally
{
    CloseConnectionToDatabase();
}
```

Comment: Well, yes and no. I have a ton of catch(rethrow scenarios in base classes - that call a logging interface to write the exception to the application log. Even IF handled further up I want to know stuff like database exceptions all the time.

Comment: @TomTom They are not consumed, they are observed then propagated. By consumed I mean swallowed never to be seen again.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth he is clearly aware of what finally does but doesn't understand why he would need it. I think it would help him. Far more than "reading the spec".

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Sorry for suggesting how you could improve your answer. I am trying to help people. I see you deleted the comment in question. Sorry I didn't mean to touch a nerve.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8914/discussion-between-anthonyblake-and-adam-houldsworth)

Answer (score 3):

As you know the code written inside the finally block always runs. 
Please have a look onto the following point written below, it will clear  your all confusion.

1. Finally is used for **Resource management. Mainly for releasing an resources**. It always runs independent upon the Exception.

   1. As we know catch is used for handle an exception, but **sometimes it fails to handle to an External exception**. **Then the finally block is used to handle that exception** to perform the operation.

Answer (score 2):

The code in the finally block will run anyway after the try-catch, it is very usefull for clean up.

```
try
{
    // open resources
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // something bad happened
}
finally
{
    // close resources that are still opened
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will behave very differently depending on whether you `return` from the `try`, for example. Also - the `finally` will run even if the `catch` throws an exception (or re-throws the original exception), which will not happen without the `finally`.

So: it isn't **required**, but it will behave differently. So if you want the code to happen, put it in the `finally`.

In many ways, `try`/`finally` is much more common than `try`/`catch` or `try`/`catch`/`finally`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not absolutely have to have the `finally` block, however, having it guarantees that the code within it will always run (unless there is an exception in the finally!).

Consider the following:

```
void Method2(void) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        // do something 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        // do something 
        throw;
    } 

    // do something whenever method2 runs 
}
```

the code after the `try/catch` will not execute if an exception is thrown. Additionally, if the code within the `catch` block has an error that causes an exception (such as your logging throwing an unexpected exception) the code that should have been in the `finally` will not run, leaving and cleanup undone.

Also a `return` statement will cause that code to not be run, while the finally will still be executed (also, here you can see that the catch can be skipped too, allowing any exceptions to propogate upwards - AFTER executing the `finally`):

```
void Method2(void) 
{ 
    try 
    {  
        // do something
        return
    } 
    finally
    {     
        // do something whenever method2 runs 
    }
}
```

Whenever you have cleanup code that must be run at the end of a method, use `finally` (or if your objects implement `IDisposable` use the `using` statement).

Answer (score 0):

The finally block ensures that any code within it **ALWAYS** gets executed so if you have a return statement inside your try block or rethrow an exception within your catch block, the code inside the finally block will always execute.

It is a must if you need to ensure that something happens regardless (e.g. disposing of a resource etc)

Answer (score 0):

The big difference is that try...catch will swallow the exception, hiding the fact that an error occurred. try..finally will run your cleanup code and then the exception will keep going, to be handled by something that knows what to do with it.