# Is ContinueWith guaranteed to execute?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, continuations

I've got a bit of code that is acting as a light weight, non-blocking, critical section. I am hoping that no matter what happens with `_func` and `cancellationToken` in the `Task.Run` clause, that the continuation is guaranteed to run such that the `Exit` statement in its `finally` block will always execute.

Is it safe to assume that the finally block below, short of catastrophic failure in the process, will be executed with roughly the same guarantees that [finally normal operates with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111597/conditions-when-finally-does-not-execute-in-a-net-try-finally-block)?

```
if (Enter())
{
    Task.Run<T>(_func, cancellationToken)
        .ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
        {
            try
            {
                antecedent.Wait(cancellationToken);
                Interlocked.Exchange<T>(ref _result, antecedent.Result);
            }
            catch (AggregateException e)
            {
                Interlocked.Exchange(ref _exceptions, e);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                ResetState();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Interlocked.Exchange(ref _exceptions, new AggregateException(e));
            }
            finally
            {
                Exit();
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: i don't think so especially if `_func` throws.

Comment: @DanielA.White I believe if `_func` throws then in continuation we'll see `Faulted` status of first task with aggregated exception

Comment: If `_func` throws the continuation *will* be executed, but if `_func` never returns it will not.

Comment: furthermore, if at all possible you should refactor this code to use the async/await keywords to massively reduce the complexity in dealing with exceptions and improve readability.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The returned Task will not be scheduled for execution until the current task has completed, whether it completes due to running to completion successfully, faulting due to an unhandled exception, or exiting out early due to being canceled.

So, unless `_func` never returns (runs in an infinite loop for example), then the continuation will always run.

And when the continuation runs, the finally block is guaranteed to execute as per the rules of C#.

So the answer is yes (unless of course `_func` never returns).

Answer (score 2):

If the token is canceled before the first task runs, the continuation will not run, and thus the finally will not execute.  Tested here with VS 2015: http://pastebin.com/9qmUYnqv

Incidentally, there are some design issues with the code as written -- having tasks modify state is not the best idea; the tasks should return values and whatnot.  In this particular case, for a nonblocking critical sections, consider using SemaphoreSlim.

Comment: The state there-in is not global,but rather instance, but point taken. I'll take a look gap between enter and run.