# 'Transition into COM context for this RuntimeCallableWrapper failed' error in parallel programming

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have some methods which are calling SPs from SQL Server. In UI I am calling methods using parallel Programming like below:

```
Parallel.Invoke(
()=>{value1=GetData1(filterCriteria); },
()=>{value2=GetData2(filterCriteria); },
()=>{value3=GetData3(filterCriteria); },
()=>{GetData4(filterCriteria); }
);
```

I am facing the below error.

> "Transition into COM context 0x4f0100 for this RuntimeCallableWrapper
>   failed with the following error: System call failed. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80010100 (RPC_E_SYS_CALL_FAILED)).
>   This is typically
>   because the COM context 0x4f0100 where this RuntimeCallableWrapper was
>   created has been disconnected or it is busy doing something else.
>   Releasing the interfaces from the current COM context (COM context
>   0x4f01b8). This may cause corruption or data loss. To avoid this
>   problem, please ensure that all COM contexts/apartments/threads stay
>   alive and are available for context transition, until the application
>   is completely done with the RuntimeCallableWrappers that represents
>   COM components that live inside them."

What is the possible cause and how to avoid this error? Please suggest.

Comment: are you sure your getdata functions are threadsafe? along with the com instance stuff? its good to be called in parallel?

Comment: Can you post more code? We cannot tell what GetData does.

Comment: private void btnRetrieve_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  { if (condition) { RetriveData(filterCriteria) } }       private void RetrieveData(FilterCriteria filtercriteria){ "above posted code" }

Comment: You are calling a interface (gui) component outside of the thread that created it. A invoke with a delegate would be a quick (and somewhat dirty) fix. A better idea would be to separate your gui stuff from your logic.