# Detect if an awaited Async method has not aborted

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, uwp

How can I check if an `await`ed `Async` method is running or not?

I want to create a timer that checks an awaited Async method some time after the Async was called. It will check whether it's still running or whether it had something like an `OutOfMemoryException` which will not be caught by a `try-catch` in the caller method - the call will never return.

**EDIT**

This async method might be awaited by another async method, and so on. Is there a way to check if the top async contains any asyncs that will never return?

(I'm trying to test it now, but am having a hard time creating an exception that will not be caught. I tried creating a StackOverflowException but it *was* caught by Visual Studio. Perhaps because it's my code, not some built-in async.)

Comment: An async method returns a Task. You can use the status of the Task to know what's going on

Comment: @KooKiz Thanks. Actually, this one returns an `IAsyncAction`. But I see what you mean. Do you know if the `IAsyncAction` will be faulty or will its `Status` throw an exception? (I see now I can cast it to a `Task`. Anyway, I wonder how I'm supposed to check for a non-returning Task.)

Comment: If the task is `await`ed, then any exceptions will be observed.

Comment: @StephenCleary See [my previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130987/finally-not-executed-because-of-async-in-try) where I mention that a `finally` block will _not_ always be executed as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/111617/939213). And as per [a comment on my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130987/finally-not-executed-because-of-async-in-try#comment63694719_38130987) - this might be because the Async never returns. If that's all wrong - perhaps you could help me out there.

Comment: @StephenCleary I also added an edit to this question.

Comment: @ispiro: Your previous question does not contain a [verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Reducing to a verifiable example is the first step in diagnosing your problem.